# TypeError: Cannot read property 'admin' of undefined

Tags: angular, angularfire

I an using firebase authentication in my angular project, I assign role the the users

here is my signin method

```js
SignIn(email, password) {
  return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((result) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/user'], {
          skipLocationChange: true
        })
      });
      this.SetUserData(result.user);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(`${error}`, '', 'error')
    })

}
```

```js
SetUserData(user) {
  const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument < any > = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
  const userData: User = {
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
    role: {
      admin: user.role.admin,
      member: user.role.member
    }
  }
  return userRef.set(userData, {
    merge: true
  })
}
```

When a user try to sign in it gives this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'admin' of undefined. If you check firestore,

```js
{
  emailVErified: true,
  role: {
    admin: true,
    member: false
  },
  uid:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}
```

Comment: What do you see if you console.log(user) inside the SetUserData(...) function?

Comment: @DKidwell Nothing shows at the console

Comment: That seems weird, you aren't seeing your console logs appear in your browser console? Try adding this line to the very beginning of SetUserData(...), console.log('my user object => ', user);

Comment: It seems, firebase has a static user detail which does not allow us to add custom fields,